# What is the best way to optimize sql query that hits/reads too many shared blocks?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following table in my postgres db (version 11):

```
CREATE TABLE instance
(
  id           bigserial,
  period       DATERANGE   NOT NULL,
  status       TEXT        NOT NULL,  -- (wait, active, inactive, outdated)
  position     BIGINT      NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT instance_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT instance_period_check CHECK (NOT isempty(period))
);
```

I need to change status of instances ordered by position by batches size of 1000 from java code:

```
        List<Instance> instances;
        Long position = null;
        do {
            instances = dao.getInstancesBeforePeriod(fromStatus, position);
            if (instances.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            processBatch(toStatus, instances);
            position = instances.get(instances.size() - 1).getPosition();
        } while (true);
```

`dao.getInstancesBeforePeriod(fromStatus, position)` if position == null calls the query:

```
SELECT id, status, period, position 
     FROM instance
             WHERE status = :status
                AND upper(period) < now()
            ORDER BY position
            LIMIT 1000;
```

if position != null calls the query:

```
SELECT id, status, period, position 
     FROM instance
             WHERE status = :status
                AND upper(period) < now()
                AND position > :position
            ORDER BY position
            LIMIT 1000;
```

But the first query hits/reads too many shared blocks so the query fails with timeout exception.
How can I solve the problem?

What if I'll add an index on instance table:

```
create index concurrently instance_index_status_upper_period_position
on instance(status, upper(period), position)
```

But I want to the index to keep instances ordered by position. Is it possible? Should I change the first query by adding `position > 0` to where clause to use such kind of index?

The explain analyze result for the first query:

[image]

I'll apreciate any ideas. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you post EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the slow query? Also if you want to fetch batches, why not use a cursor?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: `upper(period)`?  Does that refer to `JANUARI` in stead of something else ?

Comment: In the question I shared simplified table based on actual table on a production. Also I generated some test data. I think, I'm not allowed to share production code here. I can tell that in production `Buffers: shared hit=175243`

Comment: You do not have too many shared buffer hits. A buffer hit means Postgres found the necessary data *was already in memory* thus avoiding physical i/o. Buffer hits are orders of magnitude faster than any i/o operation. Perhaps you got a mistaken impression from your LIMIT clause, However, that clause is applied only after the query is otherwise resolved. Your query  read every row, sorted them and only then applied the LIMIT.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your query is that the selectivity of the predicate (`status = :status AND upper(period) < now() AND position > :position`) is probably bad.

What percentage of the rows does this predicate select (in average)?

Note that the `LIMIT` clause is irrelevant for the index optimisation.

In other words, that means the decomposition of the predicate into access predicate and filtering predicate cannot be done in an efficient way. Maybe (status, upper(period)) can be used as access and (position) as filtering predicate, or maybe (status, position) can be used as access and (upper(period)) is used as filtering. You should try both combinations since one may require less I/O or less index scanning than the other.

```
create index ix1 on instance(status, upper(period), position); 
create index ix2 on instance(status, position, upper(period));
```

You have `ix1` already.

Now, if the average selectivity is above 5.0% I wouldn't get my expectations too high. A full scan can be more effective.

One final trick that could help a bit is to make the index a "covering index". That is, include all selected columns from it as well. However, I doubt that it will much of a difference since it will hit the heap a maximum of 1000 times. In other words, enhance your index to:

```
create index ix3 on instance(status, upper(period), position, period, id); 
create index ix4 on instance(status, position, upper(period), period, id);
```